# Line $11x+3y-48 = 0$ tangent a graph $f(x) = \frac{4x + 3}{3x - 6}$ at $(a,b)$

Tags: tangent-line

Line $11x+3y-48 = 0$ tangent a graph $f(x) = \frac{4x + 3}{3x - 6}$ at (a,b) when $a<b$

$a-b = ...$

Find gradient of the line, df(x) / dx

$\frac{(4x+3)3 - (3x-6)(4)} {(3x-6)^2}$

Which the same as $ -11/3$

$(12x+9 - 12x + 24 ) 3= -11(3x-6)^2$

If i solve x, literally i solve $a $ right?
Is there less complicated way to solve it?

Comment: Looks your gradient has a flip in sign in the numerator. When using quotient rule it helps to remember the *numerator always starts with the denominator function*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite 
$$f(x)=\frac43+\frac{11}{3x-6}.$$
Now 
$$f'(x)=-\frac{11}{(3x-6)^2}\cdot3$$
and $f'(x)=-11/3$ gives $(3x-6)=\pm1$, that is $x=7/3$ and $x=5/3$.

Comment: How do come up with idea to make it $$f(x)=\frac43+\frac{11}{3x-6}.$$

Comment: Because it makes the derivation easier.

Comment: Yes i know the purpose. How do i can make a equation to be easier to differentiate

Comment: I presume that there's no general rule.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $$-\frac{11}{3}x+16=\frac{4x+3}{3x-6}$$ must have only on e solution.
Compute the discriminant! It is $x=3$

Comment: Sorry. The answer for (a,b) is e you meant?

Comment: Yes, it is $a=3$,and $$1\cdot 3+3\cdot b=48$$

Comment: But theres non in the options